# Programmatically connect to a wcf

Tags: .net, wcf, c#-4.0

I need help to figure out how to programmatically connect to a WCF service.

This needs to be done without knowing the about the WCF service, I only have an address. I do not have the option to add all the wcf services in the application.

The application I'm working on is going to over watch a number of other applications and verify that they are alive. Perhaps each minute or so.

I have a list of addresses to wcf services that might grow and shrink and thus I need help to build a c# function that can take an address and connect to a wcf service and then request information from that wcf service.

I've searched around a lot and not been able to find information and examples of how this is can be done with c# .net 4.0 and thus I really appreciate your help.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a wsdl file or at least know the operations you can invoke?

Comment: I think it would be good for you to know if the services have a mex endpoint, like:
<endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />

If yes then you could try connecting to that.

Comment: You need to know **at least** the ABC of the WCF endpoint: Address, Binding (protocol), Contract (what method it offers)

Comment: I do not have the wsdl files.

Comment: The only thing I know is the wcf service address, nothing more. It feels like nothing more should be needed to know to be able to do the rest programmatically and somewhat generic.

Comment: Please can you clarify what "information" you will be requesting from each WCF service. If all you need to do is ping the service you could try making an HttpWebRequest and analye the response. Good luck!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need to do is create the proxy at runtime and then use the newly created proxy to invoke the service.

This type of dynamic proxy should use the **MetadataResolver** class to download the metadata from the service and then use the **WsdlImporter** class to create the contract and binding at runtime.

After the dynamic proxy is compiled you can then invoke the operations on the service by using reflection. There is an implementation and explanation of a WCF dynamic proxy here that might get you started:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vipulmodi/archive/2006/11/16/dynamic-programming-with-wcf.aspx

And you can download the code from:

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Project/Download/FileDownload.aspx?ProjectName=netfxsamples&DownloadId=3939)

Comment: This is what I settled with and again, tanks. :-)     It is however somewhat heavy weight and I have not been able to do a light weight test.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to use [MetadataExchangeClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.metadataexchangeclient.aspx) to obtain metadata from a live WCF service, or fail with an error, that would serve as a 'ping' solution.

Comment: If I ask for the metadata that can be a lot of kbytes and if I want to check the wcf services each minute then my over watch program would create unwanted pressure so I hope there is a better solution available all thou I have not found it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use [`svcutil` tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733.aspx). You can use it to create different proxy classes (for each service you need one) and then you are able to access services in a very simple way. If a new service (with new metadata) is added to the list you simply extend your app.

For using `svcutil` you just need to know the service address. Everything else can be done automatically.

Comment: If I do that then it's not programmatically done which I need to do. I only have an address for each wcf service and they can change. If I have 100 wcf services to over watch, then that will be a lot of manual work to maintain. Thus I need it to be programmatically done.

Comment: Aha ok, them probably dynamic proxy is really the best way. However I think you will still need some mapping between your code and a coresponding method on the proxy. Personally, I would try to avoid the manual creation of the requests and responses.